# Tax implications of operating an LLC in Wyoming with an Idaho bank account?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, bank-account, limited-liability-company, idaho

I operate an LLC in Wyoming, but my local business banking options have high fees. An Idaho bank offers free business checking and is within a reasonable driving distance for the rare occasions I'd have to appear in person (probably less than once a year).

My business is online technical consulting, conducted entirely within Wyoming. My clients are in several other states, but not Idaho.

I tried to open an account with the Idaho bank, and they asked me to file with the Idaho Secretary of State (without specifying exactly what to file). I assume they mean a foreign registration statement.

Since it's an LLC, the only taxes are via members' personal income taxes. None of the members file personal income taxes in Idaho, though. Will filing a foreign registration statement in Idaho and having a bank account there cause any Idaho tax implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bank said I need to file a "Foreign Registration Statement (Limited Liability Company)" in order to comply with the bank's membership guidelines, and the Idaho State Tax Commission said in response to my emailed query:

> As long as you don’t have any Idaho source income, you don’t have an
>   Idaho filing requirement or tax liability. Just having an Idaho based
>   bank account doesn’t trigger an Idaho tax liability.

I'm sure that whatever they say via email isn't binding in court, but it seems like a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

The bank in Idaho requires you to "register" your company with the state of Idaho. In most states, the process of registering an LLC in a state requires paying an annual fee and filing annual paperwork. I don't know if registration is a requirement of this particular bank or the state of Idaho, but either way it is a nuisance for a small company to have to pay annual fees and do annual paperwork in two states (Idaho and Wyoming).

I don't think having a bank in Idaho would create any tax obligations, but I'm not a tax expert and I don't know anything about Idaho law.

I recommend one of the following:

- Find a Wyoming bank with lower fees.
- Find an Idaho bank that doesn't require you to register with the state.
- Use an online-only bank. For my latest business, I opened an account with an online-only bank called Azlo, and it does everything I need without any fees.

Comment: I marked my own answer as correct b/c it answers the specific question, but your recommendation of Azlo was helpful!